# Flow is not refreshed when Room database table record is updated

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

I'm updating the `is_in_cart` column in the Room Database for the `ShoppingListItem` when the add-to-shopping-cart `Checkbox` is clicked. I have a separate `LazyColumn items` section to list the items in the cart, but when the checkbox is clicked, it is not showing the list of items in the shopping cart. The `Room` database is not triggering a fresh retrieval of the `Flow` from the database when the item is updated. How can I fix this?

**ShoppingListItem**

```
@Parcelize
data class ShoppingListItem(
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val shoppingListId: Long = 0L,
  
    ...

    val isInCart: Boolean = false
): Parcelable
```

**ShoppingListItemEntity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "shopping_list_items",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ShoppingListEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("shopping_list_id"),
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class ShoppingListItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopping_list_id")
    var shoppingListId: Long = 0L,

    ...

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_in_cart")
    val isInCart: Boolean
)
```

**Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId")
fun getAllShoppingListItems(listId: Long): PagingSource<Int, ShoppingListItemEntity>
```

**Repository**

```
override fun getAllShoppingListItems(listId: Long): Flow<PagingData<ShoppingListItem>> {

    val pagingSourceFactory = { shoppingListItemDao.getAllShoppingListItems(listId) }

    return Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
    ).flow.map {
        it.map { shoppingListItemEntity ->
            shoppingListItemMapper.mapFromEntity(shoppingListItemEntity)
        }
    }
}
```

**Use case**

```
class GetAllShoppingListItemsUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val shoppingListItemsRepository: ShoppingListItemsRepository
) {
      operator fun invoke(listId: Long): Flow<PagingData<ShoppingListItem>> {
        return shoppingListItemsRepository.getAllShoppingListItems(listId)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
suspend fun addItemToCart(item: ShoppingListItem, checked: Boolean) {
    val updatedItem = item.copy(isInCart = checked)
    updateShoppingListItemInDb(updatedItem)
}

private suspend fun updateShoppingListItemInDb(item: ShoppingListItem) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        updateShoppingListItemUseCase(item)

        _listItemsLoadingState.value = ListItemsState.Success(_shoppingListItemsState.value)
    }
}
```

**Composable**

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
successItems = allItemsState.allItems?.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

val itemsNotInCart = successItems!!.itemSnapshotList.filter {
    !it!!.isInCart
}

val itemsInCart = successItems!!.itemSnapshotList.filter {
    it!!.isInCart
}

LazyColumn(
    state = alphaLazyListState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        start = 0.dp,
        end = 0.dp,
        bottom = 165.dp
    ),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(3.dp),
) {
    itemsIndexed(
        items = itemsNotInCart,
        key = { index, item ->
            item.id
        }
    ) { index, item ->
        ShoppingListScreenItem(
            item = item,
            mainViewModel = shoppingListScreenViewModel,
            sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel,
            onNavigateToAddEditItemScreenFromItemStrip = { shoppingListItem ->
                onNavigateToAddEditItemScreenFromItemStrip(
                    shoppingListItem
                )
            },
        ) { isChecked ->
            scope.launch {
                shoppingListScreenViewModel.addItemToCart(
                    item,
                    isChecked
                )
            }
        }
        Divider()
    }

    if (itemsInCart.isNotEmpty()) {
        stickyHeader {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background("#bcd8c1".hexToColor())
                    .padding(7.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Shopping Cart")
            }
        }

        items(
            items = itemsInCart,
            key = { item ->
                item.id
            }
        ) { item ->
            ShoppingListScreenItem(
                item = item,
                mainViewModel = shoppingListScreenViewModel,
                sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel,
                onNavigateToAddEditItemScreenFromItemStrip = { shoppingListItem ->
                    onNavigateToAddEditItemScreenFromItemStrip(
                        shoppingListItem
                    )
                },
            ) { isChecked ->
                scope.launch {
                    shoppingListScreenViewModel.addItemToCart(
                        item,
                        isChecked
                    )
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change ````fun getAllShoppingListItems(listId: Long): PagingSource<Int, ShoppingListItemEntity>```` to ````fun getAllShoppingListItems(listId: Long): Flow<PagingSource<Int, ShoppingListItemEntity>>````

Comment: I changed it, but it gives me the following error: `error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`.

Comment: are you using suspend also in this?

Comment: No, I'm not using suspend anywhere for retrieving all shopping list items.